# Only Magento bundle product is not showing option in Backend (Only Bundle Product) -magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, bundled-product

In Admin product detail, other products are showing properly. Only Bundle products are missing product information.

[image: below is the image that is appear in backend in magento]

I am not getting any error in console.

Comment: Check the browser's dev tool's Javascript console - probably there is some error message.

Comment: I got the same issue